# C# graphics slow

Tags: c#, graphics

I have been learning C# in Visual Studio 2013 and have run in to a problem.
I am drawing a bunch of dots (right now, 20) moving across the screen. Between refreshes (every ms), I call clear the graphics. However, this causes the dots I'm drawing after I clear to be erased. The end result of this is the dots appear to be flashing across the screen. I am a Java programmer, and I approached this graphics the way I would in Java. Is this wrong? What can I do to fix my problem?

I believe the error comes from the fact that my tick method takes about 9 ms to run.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace AstroidBlast {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        Random r = new Random();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer gameTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        Particle[] particles = new Particle[20];
        int tick = 0;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            gameTimer.Interval = 1;
            gameTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(gameTimer_Tick);
            gameTimer.Start();
            this.Width = 800;
            this.Height = 600;
            for (int i = 0; i < particles.Length; i++) {
                particles[i] = new Particle(new Velocity(r.Next(0, 360) * (Math.PI / 180), r.NextDouble() *.75 + 0.25), 100, 100, r);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
        private void gameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            for (int i = 0; i < particles.Length; i++)
                particles[i].draw(g, Math.Sqrt(tick++));
            s.Stop();
            Debug.Print(s.ElapsedMilliseconds + "");
        }
    }
    class Particle {
        static SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40));
        Random r;
        Velocity velocity;
        double x, y;
        public Particle(Velocity v, double x, double y, Random r){
            velocity = v;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.r = r;
        }
        public void draw(Graphics g, double t) {
            g.FillEllipse(brush, (int)(velocity.speed * t * Math.Cos(velocity.angle) + x), (int)(velocity.speed * t * Math.Sin(velocity.angle) + y), 8, 8);
        }
    }
    class Velocity {
        public double angle, speed;
        public Velocity(double angle, double speed) {
            this.angle = angle;
            this.speed = speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Between refreshes (every ms), I call clear the graphics` which is where?

Comment: 1) You are constantly calling `this.CreateGraphics()` and never disposing of it. 2) 99.9% of the time you should not be doing `this.CreateGraphics()` and should be overriding the `OnPaint` event and doing the drawing in there instead.

Comment: Oops, I replaced that with covering everything with a rectangle to see if that fixed it. Changing it back now.

Comment: _Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();_ __Never__ do this! Only use the `Paint` event's `e.Graphics`!! Also: do not even try to do anything UI related at ms intervals!

Comment: You trigger it by calling Invalidate(). and since you didn't create e.Graphics you don't need to dispose of it. Since you are drawing onto the Form you also should set DoubleBuffered=true if you haven't already done so to reduce flicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, generally this is not the right way to draw in C#.

You should be overriding the `OnPaint` event, which provides you a `Graphics` object and drawing to that. Inside your timer tick, you can `Invalidate` all or some of the area to be redrawn

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    // draw here
}

private void gameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   this.Invalidate(); // optionally, provide the area to invalidate for better performance
}
```

You can also get better performance/less flickering by telling your form to use `DoubleBuffered`

```
public Form1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true
}
```

Reproducing your code with the above changes causes no significant flickering.